# Flush a left-flushed box right

Tags: horizontal-alignment, boxes, letterhead

I would like to put an address in my document as follows:

```
|                             |
|                     Name    |
|                     Street #|
|                     City    |
|                     ZIP     |
|                             |
```

where the `|` mark the left and right page borders. I would like the items of the address (Name, Street etc.) to be left-flushed, but the box right-flushed so that the longest item touches the right page border.

Is there a simple way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `tabular` for the left alignment and use `\hfill` to flush it to the right.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\begin{document}

Before

\null\hfill\begin{tabular}{l@{}}
     Name \\
     Street \# \\
     City \\
     ZIP \\
 \end{tabular}

\noindent\hrule% Show width of line
After

\end{document}
```

Comment: why do you have `\null`?

Comment: @Herbert: You are right, it works without it. Sometimes it happened to me that the *fill* macros didn't work when there wasn't a `\hbox{}` or shorter `\null` at one side, so I just got used to adding them.

Comment: It should be pointed out that this does not work if there is no empty line between `Before` and `\hfill`.

Comment: @tparker The @{} removes the intercolumn space before and after the column. In this particular case the first instance is superfluous, which is why Martin left it out, but the second is not. If you remove it, the table will no longer be flush with the right margin.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\hfill \tikz
\node [align=left]{name\\Town\\ code postal};
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\newlength{\abc}

\begin{flushright}\settowidth{\abc}{River Street}
\parbox{\abc}{\noindent
Tom Robinson\\
River Street\\
Pittsburgh\\
123456}
\end{flushright}
```