# Stretch \columnsep with left-flushed text

Tags: horizontal-alignment, multicol

My document is mainly made up of justified text, but with sections made of *two column & left flushed* text (actually verses). Below is a MWE.

As in [Flush a left-flushed box right](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13542/flush-a-left-flushed-box-right), I want the text of the second column to be:

- left flushed, and
- that the longest line of this secund colum is also left-flushed and right-aligned ?

Here, a shema, where `|` are the limits of text area:

```
|Some normally justi-|
|fied text.          |
|                    |
|Foo            Fus  |
|Bar            Roooh|<- the right end of the longest line matches the text-area limit
|Baz            Da!  |
```

As I want the solution to be generic, and as I don't necessary know the number of lines of the "two-columned" text (there could be a `pagebreak` in it), I found the solution suggested in the [thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13542/flush-a-left-flushed-box-right) (and in its [duplicate](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46725/how-to-flush-right-but-align-left)) made of a `tabular`+`\hfill` not convinient.

**Question:** Is there a simple way to stretch the `\columnsep` dimension used in the `multicols` environment, as an `\hfill` would do?

---

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

    \usepackage{multicol}
    \usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]

    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \noindent
        Foo foo foo\newline
        Bar, barbar\newline
        Bazbazbaz baz babaz

        \noindent
        Fusss fus,\newline
        Roh\newline
        Daaaa !
    \end{multicols}

    \noindent\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: `varwidth` package might help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are manually breaking the lines anyway it is easiest to box them (otherwise if you let TeX's normal paragraph breaker break the paragraph in to lines, they will all be full width even if they have short text).

[image]

If each line is its natural width you just have to unbox and re-box the right hand column so that the column is set to the width of its content then the existing glue that multicols uses will push the column to the right.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

    \usepackage{multicol}
    \usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\def\mc@align@columns{%
     \process@cols\mult@gfirstbox{%
       \ifdim\dp\count@>\dimen\tw@
         \global\dimen\tw@\dp\count@ \fi
       \mc@col@status@write
       \box\count@
       \hss{\columnseprulecolor\vrule
              \@width\columnseprule}\hss}%
     \ifdim\dp\mult@rightbox>\dimen\tw@
       \global\dimen\tw@\dp\mult@rightbox \fi
     \mc@lastcol@status@write
     \vbox{\unvbox\mult@rightbox}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]

    \begin{multicols}{2}

        \hbox{Foo foo foo}
        \hbox{Bar, barbar}
        \hbox{Bazbazbaz baz babaz}

\bigskip

        \hbox{Fusss fus,}
        \hbox{Roh}
        \hbox{Daaaa !}
    \end{multicols}

    \noindent\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```